# what do you call the person who likes to do things by himself?

Tags: american-english, international

what do you call the person who likes to do things by himself ? I mean to say like do everyday life work from cleaning cloths to preparing food... no matter how hard the works become. Having such a motivation that "Its my job and I have to do it" and feeling pleasured by doing himself instead of handing the jobs over to others.

EDIT: don't like much dependency on others and it might sound strange but likes to stay totally dependent on only "ONE" person (I meant to say GOD).

EDIT: He is not independent. He still needs to depend on his family for money/housing/personal stuffs/food/education/medical care etc. But what I am looking for is word that defines the "habit" of a person who likes to do things by himself. For example, his mom is going to the shop, he can just tell his mom to bring a particular book for him, but instead he goes along with her or goes in another time to buy the book himself/in his presence.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are looking for is Lone-Wolf

> Cambridge Reference
>
> A person who likes to do things on their own without other people
> http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lone-wolf

Comment: I like it... "Lone-wolf" sounds cool. Self-reliance and Lone-wolf, I think I got it.